# PHP Update MySQL DB with AJAX call isn't doing anything

Tags: php, ajax, database, json, sql-update

I'm trying to update a field on my database with PHP and AJAX

I have tested and found that the correct data is being sent, but the PHP that is handling the update is not working correctly.

All that happens is that I get the `else` response in conditional.

I need to update the DB depending on what the user input is.

Like I said, all I get for the response is the `else` response.

```
$youruname = $_POST['youruname'];
$selectedplayer = $_POST['selectedplayer'];
$selPlayerUname = $_POST['selPlayerUname'];

$flag = "";
$itStatus = "";

$checkit = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT it FROM login WHERE uname='$selPlayerUname'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($checkit))
{
    $itStatus = $row["it"];
}

if($itStatus == "not it")
{
    mysqli_query("UPDATE login SET it = CASE WHEN uname = '$youruname' THEN 'not it' ELSE 'it' END WHERE uname IN ('$youruname', '$selPlayerUname')");

    $flag = "success";
}
else if($itStatus == "it")
{
    $flag = "nope";
}
else
{
    $flag = "error";
}
echo json_encode(array("message" => $flag, "tagged" => $selectedplayer));

mysqli_free_result($checkit);
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: var_dump($iStatus) what does it return

Comment: Warning: your queries are vulnerable to SQL injection. Please switch to [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).

Comment: On your update query you have 'SET it = CASE' if CASE is a column there is no problem, but, if is not? Also, your code is vulnerable to sql injection. Learn how to use prepared statements.

Comment: I'm going to switch to prepared statements once I get it working. I've gotten that a lot about injection. I know I need to, but am just fixing one problem at a time. Thank you for the concern, though

Comment: One other thing, Add to your queries an error output... you can use `...or die(mysqli_error());` for example. It will tell you what's your query issue. And Please, Don't let security flaws for last.

Comment: @GGio its coming up empty. Ok, so why? I have no idea why it is.

Comment: @LuigiSiri I'll do that to the query, but the problem is that `$itStatus` is coming up empty, a blank string. But why? I have no idea. I know for a fact that I'm sending the correct data. What else can I look for?

Comment: Check what `$selPlayerUname` returns.

Comment: its coming up empty because the last row of your query has its value empty and you are setting $iStatus and overwriting it in the loop so it only gets the last value. look at my answer. Or your $_POST data is not right

Comment: I just figured it out. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There is something confusing here. You have a loop and after loop conditionals. Shouldnt your update query be inside a loop like:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($checkit))
{
    $itStatus = $row["it"];


    if($itStatus == "not it")
    {
       mysqli_query("UPDATE login SET it = CASE WHEN uname = '$youruname' THEN 'not  it' ELSE 'it' END WHERE uname IN ('$youruname', '$selPlayerUname')");

       $flag = "success";
    }
    else if($itStatus == "it")
    {
       $flag = "nope";
    }
    else
    {
       $flag = "error";
    }
}
```

Your **$iStatus** gets the last value from the database since its in the loop and then you check in conditionals

If above does not help then check your **$_POST** values to see if any of them are **blank** or **null** and do the query on **PHPMyAdmin** see if it actually returns anything.

Comment: I needed to pass the connection to the `mysqli_query` as well. I wasn't doing that. But, you raised a great point about the loop and where to put the query for updating. So for that, I thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_query` requires you to pass the connection.

I wasn't doin that.

When I passed the values to the query directly, I figured it out.

Thank you very much for the help everyone